# unittesting with random variables in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, random

I am trying to test this Module I wrote for a game. The module is supposed to roll dice, and add the result. later they are checked for things like skill check and such, so I wanted to make sure that it is working correctly.

```
import random

def roll3d6():
  return random.choice(1, 6) + random.choice(1, 6) + random.choice(1, 6)

def rolld100():
  return random.choice(1, 100)
```

Here is my test

```
import Roll

from unittest import TestCase

class test_Roll(TestCase):
  def test_simple(self):
    roll = Roll.roll3d6(), Roll.rolld100()
    self.assertEqual(roll)
```

And here was my testing results, what am I doing wrong?

```
    PS C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\GitHub\pickett\pickett> python -m unittest discover
    .E.
    ======================================================================
    ERROR: test_simple (test.test_Roll.test_Roll)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\GitHub\pickett\pickett\test\test_Roll.py", line 7, in test_simple
        roll = Roll.roll3d6(), Roll.rolld100()
      File "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\GitHub\pickett\pickett\Roll.py", line 4, in roll3d6
        return random.choice(1, 6) + random.choice(1, 6) + random.choice(1, 6)
    TypeError: choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

    FAILED (errors=1)
    PS C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\GitHub\pickett\pickett>
```

Edit: So I changed to randint, and now I get this type error, which i was worried about originally, not sure how to syntax this out.

```
PS C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\GitHub\pickett\pickett> python -m unittest discover
.E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_simple (test.test_Roll.test_Roll)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\GitHub\pickett\pickett\test\test_Roll.py", line 8, in test_simple
    self.assertEqual(roll)
TypeError: assertEqual() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
PS C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\GitHub\pickett\pickett>
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to unittest the `random` module? That's well outside the scope of your code.

Comment: I dislike using random numbers in testing. Each time you run the tests, you are running a different test.

Comment: Closely related / cross-site duplicate: [Python 2.7 - What are good unit tests to cover the use case of rolling a die?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/225523).

Comment: [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) only takes one argument (two if you count the implicit `self`). You're passing it one too many arguments.

Comment: Probably means randint

Comment: edited to add new error, should i make a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `random.choice()` wrong; it expects a *sequence* to pick from. You could use `random.choice(range(1, 7))`, albeit that that's not very efficient.

To get a random number between 1 and 6 (inclusive), use `random.randint():

```
random.randint(1, 6)
```

Testing the functionality of the `random` module is a) outside of the scope of your unittest, and b) rather hard, as the module always produces random results.

You'd instead stub out (mock) the functions the `random`  module provides and test if those stubs were called correctly, according to your understanding of how they should be called. See [What are good unit tests to cover the use case of rolling a die?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225523/python-2-7-what-are-good-unit-tests-to-cover-the-use-case-of-rolling-a-die).

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, your tests worked, and they have found a bug!

The bug is that you're calling `random.choice` with 2 arguments, while it takes only one, a sequence (usually a list).

You probably meant to use `random.randint(1, 6)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `choice()` takes exactly 2 arguments (the `(3 given)` means that there is a third argument passed implicitely to choice (probably `self`)).

Indeed, [`choice()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.choice) only takes *one* argument, which has to be aa sequence (list, tuple, …).

What you want is actually [`random.randint`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.randint) and not `random.choice`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.randint(1, 6)` to get random numbers between 1 and 6 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice()` expects a SET to be passed in, so the following would work instead:

```
random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

This would be prohibitive with 100 choices, so I recommend using the following instead:

```
random.randint(a, b)
```

Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.